# Is there any error correction experimental set-up based on stationary-flying hybrid systems?

Tags: resource-request, stabilizer-code, photonics

In a [former question of mine](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26885/on-the-photonic-implementation-of-shors-code) I asked to detail the functioning of a photonic based set-up encoding a quantum state within a Shor code.

I would like to be updated on the eventual existence of any experimental set-up where people attempted to generate a logical state within a hardware settings based on both stationary (e.g. ions) and flying (e.g. photons) systems.